# React Native Issue Highlighting Hashtags/Mentions in TextInput as User Types

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm attempting to create a TextInput that detects and highlights `#hashtags` or `@mentions` as the user types. [I'm using the code from this gist](https://gist.github.com/scf4/012e9f615f6b43a1712a083b162afd94) as a starting point which, from the GIFs on the gist, appears to do exactly what I want. However, I'm seeing some unexpected lag when I implement this solution.

I have "mention" color set to red, and all other text set to green. You'll notice in the GIF that after I move the cursor back to the highlighted portion of the code, then press space and start typing again, each letter from then on is very briefly colored red then flips to green. It's very subtle, and only appears to happen if I move the cursor back to a highlighted word and start typing from there.

I observed the same behavior on iOS simulator (14.5 and 15.2), a physical device (15.2) running Expo Go, and when running the app from Xcode directly on my physical device (outside of Expo Go).

How can I avoid the delay in formatting?

[image]

This is a fresh react native project created via `expo init`. The entirety of the project is pasted below:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactnativeplayground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [testFormattedContent, setTestFormattedContent] = React.useState('');

  const handleChangeText = (inputText) => {
    const retLines = inputText.split("\n");
    const formattedText = [];
    retLines.forEach((retLine) => {
      const words = retLine.split(" ");
      const contentLength = words.length;
      var format = /[ !#@$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\n]/;
      words.forEach((word,index) => {
        if (
          (word.startsWith("@") && !format.test(word.substr(1))) ||
          (word.startsWith("#") && !format.test(word.substr(1)))
        ) {
          const mention = (
            <Text key={index} style={{ color: 'red' }}>
              {word}
            </Text>
          );
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) formattedText.push(mention, " ");
          else formattedText.push(mention);
        } else {
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) return formattedText.push(word, " ");
          else return formattedText.push(word);
        }
      });
    });

    setTestFormattedContent(formattedText);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1, margin: 50, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={handleChangeText}
      >
        <Text>{testFormattedContent}</Text>
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: are you using only expo managed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** *I improved my solution so it can handle multiline text and placeholder text. I packaged it in a custom component with a helper function. I also improved the explanations. I put the solution on top and the explanations below.*

**The snack expo:**

https://snack.expo.dev/@misterorrange/user-mention-highlight

**The helper function:**

```js
const validateMention = (word) => {
    var format = /[ !#@$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\n]/;
    if (
        (word.startsWith('@') && !format.test(word.substr(1))) ||
        (word.startsWith('#') && !format.test(word.substr(1)))
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
export default validateMention;
```

**The Custom Component:**

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import validateMention from './helpers/validateMention';

/**
 * @props
 * style: React.StyleSheet
 *
 * placeholder: string | default: 'Type something ...'
 *
 * placeholderTextColor: hexColor | default: #8e8e8e
 */

const FormattedTextInput = (props) => {
    const {
        style,
        placeholder = 'Type something ...',
        placeholderTextColor = '#8e8e8e',
    } = props;
    const [testFormattedContent, setTestFormattedContent] = useState('');
    const refTextInput = useRef(null);

    const handleChangeText = (inputText) => {
        const retLines = inputText.split('\n');
        const formattedText = [];
        retLines.forEach((retLine, index) => {
            if (index !== 0) formattedText.push('\n');
            const words = retLine.split(' ');
            const contentLength = words.length;
            words.forEach((word, index) => {
                if (validateMention(word)) {
                    const mention = (
                        <Text key={index} style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                            {word}
                        </Text>
                    );
                    if (index !== contentLength - 1)
                        formattedText.push(mention, ' ');
                    else formattedText.push(mention);
                } else {
                    if (index !== contentLength - 1)
                        return formattedText.push(word, ' ');
                    else return formattedText.push(word);
                }
            });
        });
        setTestFormattedContent(formattedText);
    };

    return (
        <View
            style={[styles.container, style]}
            onTouchStart={() => {
                refTextInput.current.focus();
            }}
        >
            <Text style={styles.text}>{testFormattedContent}</Text>
            <TextInput
                ref={refTextInput}
                style={styles.text_input}
                onChangeText={handleChangeText}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
                multiline={true}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 50,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
    },
    text_input: {
        color: 'transparent',
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
    },
    text: {
        position: 'absolute',
    },
});
export default FormattedTextInput;
```

**Explanations:**

**The problem:**

The letter typed in the TextInput sometime have very briefly the wrong color.

**Deducing the cause of the problem:**

From your code, we can see you are only setting the color of the text one time per user input.
So we can deduce that something is adding a falsy colored letter quicker then your code has time to finish.

**Performance and the Big O notation:**

To mesure the performance of a function in computer science we use the Big O notation.

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.
> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their run time or space requirements grow as the input size grows.

**In other terms:**

Big O notation describes the complexity of your code.
For example, imagine you have a simple for loop going through an array:

```js
let integer = 0
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const element = array[i];
    integer+=i;
}
```

As your array grows the number of time the for loop will run grows. Your for loop has a big O notation of O(n) because it will run once for each value you had to the array.

Now imagine you add another for loop inside of the first one. It will run n times but each time it will also run n times. So it will run n^2 times. In other words with a O(n^2) time complexity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

https://www.bigocheatsheet.com

**Explanation of the problem:**

When a user types a letter the `TextInput` immediately ads it to its text field.

Adding a letter to a string has a time complexity of O(1).

However your `handleChangeText`function has 2 loops so it runs with a O(n^2) time complexity.

But it also has 2 regular expression tests which each have a O(n) time complexity. So we can say it has a O(n^3) time complexity.

*In reality we say runs with a O(a*b*c) time complexity because the n values are different.*

So we can see that what is causing the problem is performance. O(1) will always be faster than O(n^3).

**The Solution:**

My first attempt at solving the issue was improving performance:

We can in fact reduce it to O(n) because it is not necessary to go through all the words each time. We only have to validate the last input of the user.

My first attempt was using `onKeyPress` instead of on `onChangeText` however a bug was appearing when the user triggers a `longPress` on the Backspace. The `onKeyPress` event is triggered multiple time at first but after a certain time it stops triggering and removes all text from the textInput which caused the state and the TextInput to be different. So I scratched that idea.

My second attempt was to use `onChangeText` but only focus on the last word. Since an array access has a time complexity of O(1), that solution was acceptable. However it didn't predictably solve the issue and added a lot of code complexity.

I then accepted that my efforts were futile since we were never going to be faster then the `TextInput`. At best we would have a time complexity of O(n) when the textInput has a time complexity of O(1).

So I changed my focus and decided to remove the displayed text from the `TextInput`, position it absolutely on top of the `TextInput` text and make the `TextInput` text invisible.

I settled on giving you the code that most predictably solved the issue with the fewest modifications to your current code.

*PS: Earlier in the React docs it was stated that you shouldn't store React Components in the state. I couldn't find it in the updated docs but I personally still avoid doing it.*

Comment: Thanks for the write-up, I appreciate the effort you put into this. I don't believe this addresses the underlying root issue, but it does provide a plausible workaround to the problem (thank you). The issue still remains unanswered: why does TextInput temporarily apply the wrong style to a child element? In other words, a character added that should have the default TextInput color applied to it manages to temporarily pickup the styling of a sibling, or vice versa (a hashtag temporarily picks up the style of the TextInput, which feels more reasonable from a performance/rendering perspective).

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it provides a workaround to the problem at hand. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear enough on the underlying issue. The `textInput` adds the letter you type immediately so your function doesn't have the time to decide what color it should be. Then when your function finishes running the state is updated and the text turns to the right color. PS: tell me if this still isn't clear.

Comment: That's how I understood it too. The delay between typing a character (immediately visible) and a custom function rendering/applying style to it makes sense. The observed behavior is that the style temporarily applied to the character you just typed isn't always the default "TextInput" style (i.e. green text in the gif). If you type `#hey` (which each character styles **red** after a slight delay), then begin typing `you`, the `y`, `o` and `u` of `you` are temporarily styled **red**. I would expect them to be styled to whatever's set on the TextInput, but instead they pickup their sibling.

Comment: From my experimentations trying to solve the issue, my understand was that if a `textInput` has `Text` elements as children it will append the text to those elements. But I don't think this situation is supposed to happen since normally `textInput` doesn't have children. `textInput` is supposed to be used as a self closing element (like I used it in my solution). At least that's how it is used in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was interesting problem so I got some time to find a work out.

The trick I found is to make the input color `transparent` and then specify
the color needed for each input you type

Here have a look

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [testFormattedContent, setTestFormattedContent] = React.useState(
    [] as any[]
  );

  const getWord = (word: string, color: string, key:number)=> {
    return (<Text key={key} style={{ color: color }}>
              {word}
            </Text>)
  }
  const handleChangeText = (inputText: string) => {
    const retLines = inputText.split('\n');
    const formattedText = [] as any[];
    retLines.forEach((retLine) => {
      const words = retLine.split(' ');
      const contentLength = words.length;
      var format = /[ !#@$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\n]/;
      words.forEach((word, index) => {
        if (
          (word.startsWith('@') && !format.test(word.substr(1))) ||
          (word.startsWith('#') && !format.test(word.substr(1)))
        ) {
          const mention = getWord(word, "red", index)
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) formattedText.push(mention, ' ');
          else formattedText.push(mention);
        } else {
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) return formattedText.push(getWord(word, "green", index), ' ');
          else return formattedText.push(getWord(word, "green", index));
        }
      });
    });

    setTestFormattedContent(formattedText);
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={{ flex: 1, margin: 50, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, color:"transparent" }} onChangeText={handleChangeText}>
          {testFormattedContent}
        </TextInput>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And this is a link to snack https://snack.expo.dev/@alentoma/textinput

Note: You need to view the snack example on android.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the same problem exists after removing the second `useState` (`testContent`).

Comment: You should also remove color:green from the all your styles

Comment: Same result after removing the `color:green` styling (which I only added for the sake of contrast).

Comment: FYI, I updated the post's code snippet to have these changes reflected in it.

Comment: Ok updated my answer, please have a look

Comment: This is a nice idea (and thank you for putting in the effort), but unfortunately after copying your code over I'm still seeing the same results. I closed out all terminals and simulators just to be sure nothing was cached. Were you able to replicate the problem an iOS device (physical or simulator)?

Comment: Yes I was able to replicate the problem on android, Snack simulator. and I got it to work.

Comment: Interesting. I tried replicating my original code in the snack but there's a bit of a lag, hard for me to tell if the issue is happening or not. Bummer. Well, I'll keep at it, thanks for the help you provided so far, it gave me some interesting ideas/direction!

Comment: Well there is a bit of lag for me too, Sorry I was talking about the color change. There is really not much to do about the lag issue. Instead you could maybe write Webview and use html and js instead. It should be very fast then.

Comment: Hey Alen -- sorry, didn't mean to turn focus on the snack lag, I only brought that up because the delay between clicking a character in the keyboard and it showing in the emulator UI made it impossible for me to see the color issue I've outlined in this post (flashing red, then green). In other words, I wasn't able to replicate the issue in the snack emulator because I couldn't see it (likely due to the delay), but I do see it on a local simulator on my machine, and on a physical device where there isn't UI refresh delays that are present in the snack.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the issue lets make it more apparent. In following code I've added delay in `handleChangeText` so that it'll take more time to execute.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [testFormattedContent, setTestFormattedContent] = React.useState('');

  const handleChangeText = (inputText) => {
    const retLines = inputText.split("\n");
    const formattedText = [];
    retLines.forEach((retLine) => {
    
      //deliberate delay 
      for(let i = 0; i<200000; i++){
       let temp = (<Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{'abc' + 'abcd'}</Text>);
      }
    
    const words = retLine.split(" ");
      const contentLength = words.length;
      var format = /[ !#@$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\n]/;
      words.forEach((word,index) => {
        if (
          (word.startsWith("@") && !format.test(word.substr(1))) ||
          (word.startsWith("#") && !format.test(word.substr(1)))
        ) {
          const mention = (
            <Text key={index} style={{ color: 'red' }}>
              {word}
            </Text>
          );
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) formattedText.push(mention, " ");
          else formattedText.push(mention);
        } else {
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) return formattedText.push(word, " ");
          else return formattedText.push(word);
        }
      });
    });

    setTestFormattedContent(formattedText);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1, margin: 50, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, fontSize:'100px', color:'green'}}
        onChangeText={handleChangeText}
      >
        <Text>{testFormattedContent}</Text>
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#fff',},
});
```

You'll notice when you type a letter it gets some color, then after `handleChangeText` executes it gets new color. 
To resolve this, we can improve execution time of the function by [profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) the code and writing better logic. But we also need to focus on the initial color the letter gets before `handleChangeText` gets called.

---

**Default color** 
To find out what color newly typed letter gets lets use following code:

```html
<View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1, margin: 50, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, fontSize:'100px', color:'green'}}
      >

        <Text style={{color:'purple'}}> </Text><Text style={{color:'red'}}>red</Text> <Text style={{color:'green'}}>green</Text> 
      </TextInput>

    </View>
```

Note, there is no `onChangeText` handler only simple editable colored text elements. There are 3 colored text elements. 1) space with purple color. 2) 'red' with red color 3) 'green' with green. As shown in following image:

[image]

The image shows states of the text as I type letter 'x' at various spots. New letters get color of previous letter. So it is apparent React remembers the style. We can not say this is a bug.

---

**Possible Solution**

Even if our method returns elements with new colors. React keeps using old remembered color/style. The remembered color is updated only when we move cursor, either by using arrow keys or backspace. I think the memorization is linked to cursor movement.
 As a workaround we can set cursor position our self after we complete our text processing:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [testFormattedContent, setTestFormattedContent] = React.useState('');
  const [sel, setSel] = React.useState({start:0,end:0});

  const handleChangeText = (inputText) => {
    const retLines = inputText.split("\n");
    const formattedText = [];
    retLines.forEach((retLine) => {
      const words = retLine.split(" ");
      const contentLength = words.length;
      var format = /[ !#@$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\n]/;
      words.forEach((word,index) => {
        let space = (<Text style={{ color: 'green' }}> </Text>);

        if (
          (word.startsWith("@") && !format.test(word.substr(1))) ||
          (word.startsWith("#") && !format.test(word.substr(1)))
        ) {
          const mention = (<Text key={index} style={{ color: 'red' }}>{word}</Text>);
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) formattedText.push(mention, space);
          else formattedText.push(mention);
        } else {
          if (index !== contentLength - 1) return formattedText.push(word, space);
          else return formattedText.push(word);
        }
   
      });
    });
    setTestFormattedContent(formattedText);

    // for the demo, setting cursor to end of the text
    // we need more implementation to allow user to edit inside the text.
    setSel({start:inputText.length, end:inputText.length})
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1, margin: 50, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, fontSize:'100px', color:'green'}}
        onChangeText={handleChangeText}
        selection={sel}
      >
        <Text style={{color:'green'}}>{testFormattedContent}</Text>
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

[Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/TetZeMjbG) link. Tested on Safari 15.2 using Expo app.

For first letters after space, we can not predict if user is going to type @ or normal character next. You'll notice that I've given green color to spaces so that there will be no glitching for green letters.

Also, in above demo I haven't handled editing in between text. For that you need more implementation. Like before processing, get current cursor position then after setting processed text set the cursor position again.